# Android Studio 2.2: Gradle 'MyApplication4' project refresh failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2

I'm using Android Studio 2.2 on Windows 8 (32-bit). I've tried every solution given over the Stack Over Flow or other forums on the internet but all in vein. Error details are given below:

> **Gradle 'MyApplication4' project refresh failed**
>   Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows that you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher

I'm mentioning again that I've tried every solution i.e. jdk location, gradle plugins refresh, uninstalling and reinstalling the Android Studio, etc. So, please help me out with any other solution.

Comment: Without more information (you don't say if the compilation worker before, if it's just this project or another one, if you updated Android Studio, if the project is your's or you got it from someone else...), it looks like it can be a conflict between the tools binaries you're running and the version of Windows you have. So, I'd suggest first a full clean (i.e. Build -> Clean on AS), then checking that you don't have any 64-bit tool somehow installed in your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your gradle version.
Try to add the dependency below:

```
dependencies {     
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'   
}
```